# How do I find the current frame rate of a playing video?

Tags: youtube

YouTube now includes support for higher framerates, and they showcased the quality difference in "[YouTube in up to 60 frames per second](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbsGxdAPhjv9UrLo19pS8teoRKj7funAy)."

In the YouTube web application I can see and change the current resolution by clicking on **`Settings > Quality`**:
<sub>[image: Resolution example]</sub>

Is there a way to also display the current framerate, for example, 30fps vs. 60fps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 60 fps Displayed if Available

When watching a video in the desktop version of YouTube's web app, where a **Quality** setting includes a framerate of 60 fps, it is noted.

If a **Quality** option includes a framerate of only 30 fps, nothing is noted.

For example, YouTube lists the following **Quality** choices for the video, "[What is Stack Exchange?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvYCoD3VrlM)":

| Quality | Resolution | Framerate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1440p60 <sup>HD</sup> | 2560x1440 | 60 fps |
| 1280p60 <sup>HD</sup> | 1920x1080 | 60 fps |
| 720p60 | 1280x720 | 60 fps |
| 480p | 854x480 | 30 fps |
| 360p | 640x360 | 30 fps |
| 240p | 426x240 | 30 fps |
| 144p | 256x144 | 30 fps |

1. You can see the current **Quality** by clicking the **Settings** cog
   <sub>[image]</sub>
2. Or, to see **all** available options, click on **Settings** cog, and then **Quality** 
   <sub>[image]</sub>

## Stats For Nerds

If you are accessing the mobile version of the YouTube web app, or are experiencing issues in the desktop version, or, for any other reason, regardless of the current framerate, you can display it and other stats for the currently playing video by enabling the **"Stats for Nerds"** overlay in either the mobile or desktop browser versions of YouTube.

### A.   Enable in Mobile

[m.youtube.com](https://www.m.youtube.com)

1. Tap on the video to expose the controls overlay with the **Playback Settings** gear icon and select it.
   <sub>[image]</sub>
2. In the **Playback Settings** dialog select **"Stats for Nerds"** and **OK**
   <sub>[image]</sub>
3. The stats overlay will show the framerate on the line labeled **"Current/Optimal Res"**
   <sub>[image]</sub>

### B.   Enable in Desktop

[youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com)

1. Right-click (long-press on mobile) the video and in the menu that appears, select **"Stats for Nerds"**
   <sub>[image]</sub>
2. Similar to mobile, the stats overlay will show the framerate on the line labeled **"Current/Optimal Res"**

Answer (score 9):

If watching a YouTube video using the Adobe Flash Player: Right click on the video, Stats for nerds:

[image]

[image]